# how to Create rotate, resize, move, delete text in Flutter Code

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-android

how   to  Create  rotate, resize, move, delete text in  Flutter  Code

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far

Comment: i am   using Sticker View  package  but Not Proper this Type OutPut

Comment: Have you got anything regarding this? @kkweb